# Linear homotopy

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $\lambda, \mu:[a,b]\longrightarrow X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ paths such that the straight line $[\lambda(s),\mu(s)]$ lies in X for all $s\in[a,b]$. Set:
$$\begin{array}{lccc}
H:&[a,b]\times[0,1]&\longrightarrow&X\\
&(s,t)&\longrightarrow&(1-t)\lambda(s)+t\mu(s)
\end{array}$$

How can I show that $H$ is continuous?

Comment: Both $\lambda,\mu$ are paths so that they are continuous. The convex combination is obviously continuous since only addition and multiplication are involved.

Comment: If $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are paths then they are necessarily continuous?

Comment: Usually this is the definition, at least in the topology books I read...

Comment: Ok, thanks!! :D

Comment: You are welcome. I have found this [wikipage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(topology)) for your consideration.

Comment: Since nobody did it, you can probably answer your own problem, in a more rigorous way.

Comment: Really? Is not out of the rules?

Comment: You are actually encouraged to do that, and may even win some sort of badge...

Comment: Can you see what I wrote? I'm not a english speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are paths, by the definition, they are continuous. $1-t$ and $t$ are clearly continuous.

So we know that the sum and product of continuous functions are continuous, therefore $H$ is continuous.